# Can a Muslim woman marry her cousin (paternal)?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, women

Can a Muslim woman marry her cousin (son of her father's brother)?

We like each other, we want to know if it is haram to marry a relative, that is too a paternal cousin? Is it acceptable in Islam?

Most people say it is haram in Islam! Is it so?

Answer (score 3):

All Praise to Allah Subhan o Taala and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions

> Prohibited to you [for marriage] are your mothers, your daughters,
>   your sisters, your father's sisters, your mother's sisters, your
>   brother's daughters, your sister's daughters, your [milk] mothers who
>   nursed you, your sisters through nursing, your wives' mothers, and
>   your step-daughters under your guardianship [born] of your wives unto
>   whom you have gone in. But if you have not gone in unto them, there is
>   no sin upon you. And [also prohibited are] the wives of your sons who
>   are from your [own] loins, and that you take [in marriage] two sisters
>   simultaneously, except for what has already occurred. Indeed, Allah is
>   ever Forgiving and Merciful. (Al-Nisa 4:23)

Yes A Muslim Woman can marry her cousin which is acceptable and its not haram at all.These are the people to whom Marraiage is not allowed: 
 Mother, grand-mother, etc.
daughters,
 sisters,
fathers sisters (paternal aunts),
 mothers sisters (maternal aunts), brothers daughters (niece),
sisters daughters (niece),
foster mother (a lady who gave suck to one as an infant),
foster sisters (a boy and a girl who took suck from the same woman),
wifes mother,
Step-daughter ,
sons wife.

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Comment: yeah. Actually the above-mentioned verse (as you submitted) will be the best answer which has named the persons who you cannot get married to. Which can be perused as the best formula. JazakAllah-Khaira